# EventHandler implemented as an anonymous inner class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wan't to use keyword `this` in refer to my main class in the `EventHandler` block, say:

```
public class Extra {

    private SuperObject object;

    public Extra() {

        Button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {

                object = new SuperObject(this);
            }
        });
    }
}

// where...

public class SuperObject {

    public SuperObject(Extra e) {

        // something
    }
}
```

But in this case I've got an warning about that I haven't declare a constructor for the `SuperObject` class with `ActionEvent` parameter in it. What can I do in such situation?

Comment: That's not actually "reflection", by the way.

Comment: I suffer for the lack of an appropriate word. Forgive me.

Comment: It's not a big crime, there is no need to beg for forgiveness.

Comment: How you could than describe my problem best with use of one word? Does it have any? So I could edit title of the question.

Comment: "How can I refer to the enclosing object in the body of an event handler?". "Enclosing object" can be "surrounding object". And if you wanted to be really explicit "event handler implemented as an anonymous inner class".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is your anonymous inner `EventHandler` class.

To access the outer `this`, use `Extra.this`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using Java 8, in addition to the other solution(s) posted, you can also replace the inner class with a lambda, in which `this` has its intuitive meaning (a reference to the surrounding object):

```
button.setOnAction(ae -> {
    object = new SuperObject(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it like this

```
object = new SuperObject(Extra.this);
```